# String to DateTime in VBA (Outlook)

Tags: parsing, datetime, vba

I never work with VBA (*or really any Microsoft development products*) however, I'm hammering out a few scripts to make Outlook better.

Anywho, given a date/time string such as:

```
Sunday, October 16, 2011 11:59:00 PM EDT
```

How could I effectively parse this into a `DateTime` object, for use with an `Outlook.TaskItem` (*which takes a `DateTime` for the `DueDate` member*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **IsDate** to check if a string is convertible to a date (in the users locale), and then use **CDate** to convert it.

Comment: Well, `IsDate()` is returning `False` on date strings in that format. I'm Googling `CDate()`, what other options do I have? I'm assuming there isn't any *magic* like PHP's `strtotime()` in VBA.

Comment: Oops, I omitted from the original question, the month is preceded by the day of the week; but I've now trimmed that and the timezone. It converts fine now, so I guess I should be good. Thanks @vzczc